# Utilizar un mismo componente en varias páginas pero cambiando datos

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

**Lo que estoy intentado de hacer es, utilizar un mismo componente, en este caso Header, en la página de inicio y en otras páginas adicionales pero cambiando los datos que se muestran.**

**La idea** de lo que quiero que mi programa compile es esta:

```js
//App.js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Nav from './components/Landing/Nav';
import Header from './components/Landing/Header';

import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      <Router>
        <Nav/>
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => {
          <Header page="index"/>
        }}>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/planes" render={() => {
          <Header page="planes"/>
        }}>
        </Route>
      </Router>
    </div>
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Es decir que, **cuando a Header le paso el parametro page="index", cargue los datos json que corresponden a "index", cuando le paso page="planes" cargue los datos que corresponden a "planes"** y así si cargo datos para otra página.

Hasta el momento tengo mi componente Header de la siguiente forma:

```js
//./components/Landing/Header.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Container, Button, Typography} from '@material-ui/core';

import dataHeader from '../../bd/header.json';
import headerImg from '../../assets/img/index/header.svg';


export default class Header extends Component {
    state = {
        dataHeader: dataHeader
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Container maxWidth="lg">
                    {this.state.dataHeader.map(e =>
                    <div key={e.index.id}>
                        <img src={headerImg} alt={e.index.image.alt}/>
                        <Typography variant="button" display="block" gutterBottom>
                            {e.index.comment}
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography variant="h3" gutterBottom>
                            {e.index.title}
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography variant="subtitle1" gutterBottom>
                            {e.index.subtitle}
                        </Typography>
                        <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
                            {e.index.button}
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                    )}
                </Container>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Y mis datos en json que corresponden a ese Header:

```js
//bd/header.json
[
    {
        "index": {
            "id": 0,
            "image":{
                "src": "../assets/img/index/header.svg",
                "alt": "header 1"
            },
            "comment": "Comentario 1",
            "title": "Titulo 1",
            "subtitle": "subtitulo 1",
            "button": "boton 1"
        },
        "planes": {
            "id": 1,
            "image":{
                "src": "../assets/img/planes/header.svg",
                "alt": "header 2"
            },
            "comment": "Comentario 2",
            "title": "Titulo 2",
            "subtitle": "subtitulo 2",
            "button": "boton 2"
        }
    }
]
```

Si en App.js quito el parametro "page="index"", la app funciona sin problemas, aunque únicamente carga los datos de "index", ya que como pueden ver, en Header.js solamente estoy llamando a esos datos.

Lo que intento hacer es que la variable, por ejemplo {e.index.title}, contenga una subvariable que reemplace "index" por "planes" o según la página que estoy viendo. Intenté con algo como {e.{this.props.page}.title} pero al parecer así no funciona.

Perdón por mi ignorancia, estoy aprendiendo a desarrollar con React y espero que me puedan ayudar. Desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score -1):

En App.js me falto agregar "return" antes de llamar al componente:

```js
<Route exact path="/" render={() => {
  return <Header page="index"/>
}}>
```

Y en Header.js la sintaxis correcta para llamar a los datos sería, por ejemplo: `{e[this.props.page].title}`